# Where is 16.04.4 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, release-management

While I was just reading through the [Xenial Xerus Release Schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule), I saw the next point release, being 16.04.4 LTS on February 15th, 2018. I was waiting 4 days for it.

> [image: Xenial Xerus Release Schedule | 16.04.4 LTS - Point Release | February 15th, 2018]

On the release date, I forgot to turn on my Ubuntu system, so I checked today on [Ubuntu Wiki/Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). Guess what I found; 16.04.3 LTS!

Does anybody know where is the 16.04.4 point release?

Comment: My 16.04 systems got the release number bumped to 16.04.4 last week.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[It was delayed](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2018-January/004270.html) due to the Meltdown and Spectre security issues. This took up a lot of everybody's time while things were patched and tested. There are *still* patches coming out for various CPUs. It's a complicated issue and the fixes are far from ideal.

Anyway, the new release date was [recently announced](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2018-February/004287.html) as the **1st of March 2018**.

Comment: Thank you for informing me! I was thinking that maybe Canonical just forgot or something for 16.04.4.

Comment: They can delay it to April as far as I care as long as the bugs we witnessed this year are worked out first.

Answer (score 15):

See https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2018-February/004287.html

From there:

> As announced previously the release of the 16.04.4 point release has
> been delayed. Seeing that things are now settling in, we have set the
> 1st of March as the new planned date release date. We expect to have
> all the required pieces available in the archive by that time and will
> provide images with all the necessary security fixes in place.
>
> On behalf of the Ubuntu Release Team,
>
> --
> Łukasz 'sil2100' Zemczak
> Foundations Team